# why I can't schedule a job on cron?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, sh

I am trying schedule a job on crontab and isn't work.

I follow the jobs at YARN.

```
10 14 * * * /home/myuser/Tes/btm.sh >/dev/null 2>/home/myuser/Tes/log_btm.log
```

None session was open.

Comment: Does file /home/myuser/Tes/btm.sh have exec permisions for crontab user?

Comment: What's your objective with btm.sh? Save the results in file or redirect it to null?

Comment: Yes, the file has permssion.

Comment: btm will input one month data in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't found any problem... Now, it's ok.